# Add lines based on logic

Tags: perl, awk, sed

Looking for a way to add three lines to a file if they dosn't exist based on some logic.

I have found the regular expressions needed to find some single and multiline patterns but doesn't know how to tie it all together.

The logic goes like this:

Add these three lines...

```
** #MEA_DATA_END **;
MEA OK;TRUE
```

...if...

```
\;(FALSE|TRUE)\;-?\d{0,3}\;-?\d{0,3}.?\d{0,3}\;\n
```

...is not followed by...

```
$\n^\*\* #MEA_DATA_END \*\*\;
```

... or when last line of file is:

```
\;(FALSE|TRUE)\;-?\d{0,3}\;-?\d{0,3}.?\d{0,3}\;\z
```

Input file that wouldn't be changed:

```
FALSE;FALSE;-1;25.0;FALSE;FALSE;-1;25.0;

** #MEA_DATA_END **;
MEA OK;TRUE
```

Input file that will be changed:

```
FALSE;FALSE;-1;25.0;FALSE;FALSE;-1;25.0;

Some other text
```

Output:

```
FALSE;FALSE;-1;25.0;FALSE;FALSE;-1;25.0;

** #MEA_DATA_END **;
MEA OK;TRUE

Some other text
```

Another input file that will be changed:

```
FALSE;FALSE;-1;25.0;FALSE;FALSE;-1;25.0;
```

Output:

```
FALSE;FALSE;-1;25.0;FALSE;FALSE;-1;25.0;

** #MEA_DATA_END **;
MEA OK;TRUE
```

I would like to create a script using sed or awk or similar. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: No problem installing ```perl```.

Comment: If so, the easiest way is to read the entire file into memory. `-0777` will cause the whole file to be treated as the line when using `-n` or `-p`.

Comment: @EdMorton: taking nothing away from `awk` Ed :) ! just wanted to state there are no straightforward ways like `-0` option in `perl`.

Comment: @Inian the awk equivalent of `-v RS='\0'` seems pretty straightforward to me and has the benefit of being consistent with how you'd specify any other char as the record separator, it's not unique to NUL.

Comment: @EdMorton: I've removed my comment Ed! Again nothing against `awk`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite right and I don't have time to debug it right now but the approach is to separate your records by the multi-line string you do NOT want replaced and then within each record replace the string you do want replaced:

```
BEGIN { RS=";(FALSE|TRUE);-?[0-9]{0,3};-?[0-9]{0,3}.?[0-9]{0,3};\n\n[*][*] #MEA_DATA_END [*][*];"; ORS="" }
{ print gensub(/;(FALSE|TRUE);-?[0-9]{0,3};-?[0-9]{0,3}.?[0-9]{0,3};/,"&\n\n** #MEA_DATA_END **;","g") RT }
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT. You'd save it in a file named `foo.awk` and then execute it as `awk -f foo.awk inputfile`. You could save the leading regexp part in a variable to save having to hard-code it twice.